# How do we rule according to Genises 1:28, What do we do, how do we exercise this rule

Tags: rule

Gen 1:28, How do we rule over that which God instructed.
What is rule?
What do we do?

> Gen 1:28 (NASB) - God blessed them; and God said to them, “Be fruitful
> and multiply, and fill the earth, and subdue it; and rule over the
> fish of the sea and over the birds of the sky and over every living
> thing that moves on the earth.”

Answer (score 2):

The pertinent verb in Gen 1:26, 28 is רָדָה (radah) = "to have dominion, rule, dominate" (Strong's & BDB), or "to subjugate" (Word Study Dictionary, Baker & Carpenter).

This verb occurs 27 times in the OT and is mostly used to describe:

- the rule/dominion of a king or ruler over his people, eg, Lev 26:17, Num 24:17, 19, Judges 5:13, 1 Kings 4:24, 5:16, 9:23, etc.
- the rule of a master over a slave, eg, Lev 25:43, 46, 53.
- The rule of supervisor over his men, eg, 2 Chron 8:10.
- The authority of the priesthood, Jer 5:31

The answer to the meaning of this word in Gen 1:26, 28 is partially answered in gen 2 where Adam and Eve are commanded to:

- (Gen 2:15) Then the LORD God took the man and placed him in the Garden of Eden to **cultivate and keep** it.

The two verbs used here perfectly describe the type of activity and "rule" that mankind was to have over nature:

- "cultivate" עָבַד (abad) = to work, serve, eg, Gen 2:5, 15, 3:23, 4:2, 12, etc.
- "tend/keep" שָׁמַר (shamar) = to keep, watch, preserve, eg, Gen 2:15, 3:24, 4:9, 17:9, 10, 18:19, etc.

That is, this rule of all nature was a matter of working it productively BUT also keeping and preserving/guarding nature as well.  That is, man's rule was not to be an exploitative rule.